# How to determine if a number is polygonal for a polygon with s sides

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, number-theory

A polygonal number is defined as being a number represented as dots arranged in the shape of a regular polygon.

For example:

Triangular numbers are 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, ...
[image]

Square numbers are 0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, ...
[image]

Pentagonal number are 0, 1, 5, 12, 22, 35, 51, 70, 92, 117, ...
[image]

and so on...

---

There are well known formulas to calculate any of these numbers. To calculate the n-th s-gonal number, one can use the formula (n^2 * (s - 2) - (n * (s - 4))) / 2

What I would like to know is, is there an efficient way to check if a given number is s-gonal for a given s?

The obvious approach would be to take successive values from a function that generates s-gonal numbers until either n is found, or the values exceed n, however this has linear time complexity.

I know there are formulas that can be used to determine if a number is s-gonal for specific values of s, but I would like one that works for any s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Wikipedia's article on Polygonal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number) I can up with the following predicate that seems to solve the problems I ran into with the one the OP proposed:

```
def isPolygonal(s, x):
    ''' Check if x is a s-gonal number '''
    assert s > 2 and s % 1 == 0 and x % 1 == 0
    # Determine if x is some nth s-gonal number,
    # fail if n doesn't come out a whole number
    n = (sqrt(8 * (s - 2) * x + (s - 4) ** 2) + (s - 4)) / (2 * (s - 2))
    return n % 1 == 0
```